# In Phonegap i get error assest.html while executing this index.html file

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have just started phonegap and when i run this code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="windows/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            var deviceReady = false;
            function init() {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
                    deviceReady = true;
                }, false);  

                window.setTimeout(function() { // Always this condtion met
                    if (!deviceReady) {
                        alert("Error: Phonegap did not initialize.  Demo will not run correctly.");
                        console.log("Error: Phonegap did not initialize.  Demo will not run correctly.");
                    }
                }, 3000);
            }

            function doAlert() {
                var message = "This is an Alert dialog";
                var title = "Attention!";
                navigator.notification.alert(message, title);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="init();">
        <h1>Cordova Tests</h1>
        <div id="info">
            <button onclick="doAlert();">
                Click Me
            </button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i run this code i am get this error

> 03-19 16:37:40.998: E/Web Console(854): TypeError: Result of
>   expression 'navigator.notification' [undefined] is not an object. at
>   file:///android_asset/www/index.html:25

Thanks in Advance freinds i hope you are understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have included the correct Cordova.js file in your index.html file? You should always make sure that the name of your Cordova file should match with the one that you have in your index file.

Check your:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="windows/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: But why "windows/cordova-2.0.0.js"???? You have no sub folder called "windows". It should be just src="cordova-2.0.0.js". Try this and see if the issue persists.